# How to use a COM-Wrapper?

Tags: c#, vb.net, com, com-interop

Question:

I have to work (in VB.NET) with an application (Aperture)'s  OLE automation via COM-Wrapper.

Currently, I switch off option strict, and do it like this (using late-binding):

```
Dim m_Aperture As Object = CreateObject("Aperture.Application")
Dim m_Project As Object = m_Aperture.Project
```

You see the problem, everything is an object, no intellisense, etc.
Very bad.

Since I want to get intellisense and and compile-time checking to work, I tried to automatically create a COM-wrapper like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\TlbImp.exe" OEAPP.TLB /out:Aperture.dll
```

So far worked splendidly, it created the wrapper, I can use intellisense on it (return types are all of type dynamic though).

[image]

So I tried to rewrite just the above sample code (now in C#):

First attempt was:

```
Aperture.OEAppClass app = new Aperture.OEAppClass();
```

But I got this compiler error:

```
Interop-Type Aperture.OEAppClass cannot be embedded. Use interface instead.
```

So i tried to do it via interface:

```
Aperture.OEApp Ap = (Aperture.OEApp)Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject("Aperture.Application");
```

That got me an exception at runtime

```
InvalidCastException
"System.__ComObject" cannot be converted into interface type "Aperture.OEApp".
0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)).
```

So I tried to figure out the interface type using

```
dynamic Ap2 = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject("Aperture.Application");
```

and object-inspector.

I found out the interface is actually of type Aperture._IOEApp.
So I used

```
Aperture._IOEApp Ap = (Aperture._IOEApp)Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject("Aperture.Application");
```

But now I get

```
InvalidCastException
"System.__ComObject" cannot be converted into interface type "Aperture._IOEApp".
0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)).
```

Now I don't know what the problem could be anymore.

Can anybody tell me what I do wrong ?
Or how this is supposed to work ?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong.  The exception says the COM server did something wrong.  It crashed.  No obvious reason for it to crash, other than that it just really doesn't like anything but late binding.  Contact the vendor to ask why.

Comment: Or, another possible reason is marshaling, the object is free threaded (MTA) and the code is from STA, COM server does not do marshaling right - again to be fixed/troubleshooted from COM server side.